# Ruby on Rails Find Where No Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, analytics

I have the following associations:

```
Outlet => has_many :checkins
Checkin => belongs_to :outlet
```

Every day, and Outlet needs to get 1 checkin.
I can get the list of outlets with a checkin made today with this:

```
Checkin.where('DATE(created_at) = ?', Date.Today)
```

However, I am not sure about how I could get a list of outlets that have not had a checkin associated with them today.

> So if **Outlet A** had a check in record created today, but **Outlet B** had not had a check in, and hence no record made, Outlet B would be returned.

If we say that:

```
@checkin_outlet_name = Checkin.where('DATE(created_at) = ?', Date.Today).outlet.name

@outlet = Outlet.all
```

I would theoretically be able to find all the Outlets without checkins made today, because all the records that are in **@outlet** and NOT on **@checkin_outlet_name** would be the ones I am looking for.

However, I have no idea how to achieve this in Rails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like `Outlet.joins(:checkins).where("DATE(checkins.created_at) <> ?", Date.today)`

Comment: No, I've not tried this before. What does the '<> ?' mean?
I'm sorry for such a noobish question - but I'm new to Rails :)

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesn't seem to do what I need it to do.

I need to fetch the list of outlets that have not yet had a checkin created for them today.

Comment: I had a typo, it should be Date.today, not Date.Today.

Comment: I had already corrected the Date.today error. But I can't quite figure out what this is supposed to do :(

Comment: The <> operator simply means different than - you want the dates that are not equal to today's date.

Comment: I dont think you quite understood, I want to find all the outlets that have not had a checkin associated with them today. This would give me all the checkins made on every day except today.

Comment: This works in the sense that it will flag it up if an outlet had been checked into on a previous day, but not today.
But does not work if an Outlet has never been checked into before.
I think so anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without writing complex queries,

```
class Outlet
  scope :checked_in_today, { joins(:checkins).where("DATE(checkins.created_at) = ?", Date.today) }
end

# remove items from Outlet.all which have been checked in today (Array - Array)
@not_checked_in_today = Outlet.all - Outlet.checked_in_today
```

Better way to do it in DB

```
class Outlet
  scope :not_checked_in_today, lambda {
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM checkins WHERE created_at = #{Date.today.to_s(:db)}) c ON outltes.id = c.outlet_id"). #only select checkins created today
    where("c.outlet_id IS NULL"). # only keep outlets not checked in today
    select("DISTINCT outlets.*") # remove duplicates 
  }
end

@not_checked_in_today = Outlet.not_checked_in_today
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

`/app/models/outlet.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC`

This does sound like the solution I was looking for, I hope this works.

Comment: I haven't worked with ActiveRecord in a long time, so syntax might be a little bit off. Try removing the curly braces.

Comment: There was also an extra curly brace in string interpolation.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the { should be prefixed by lambda?

Comment: Not always, but in this case yes. `lambda` is generally used to delay running of code until scope is actually called. Looking at the solution again I feel that you would need `lambda { .. }` here. Otherwise in your production environment, Date.today will be calculated at application startup and would be cached.